# When there is no PerformClick() in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to use PerformClick() in asp.net webforma but found that can't be used. Any replacement for this PerformClick. I also have write the code as below but still have no idea. Thank you.

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.ButtonEnter.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonEnter_Click);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Button.PerformClick()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(v=vs.110).aspx) has namespace `System.Windows.Forms`, therefore you can't use it in ASPX page's code behind.

Assumed `ButtonEnter` is a button server control, you can simulate button click programmatically in 2 ways:

1) Direct calling server-side `Click` event handler method

```
ButtonEnter.Click(sender, eventArgs);
```

**Note:** Adjust both `sender` & `eventArgs` arguments depending on your requirements.

2) Using client-side event handler & `RegisterStartupScript`

**JS**

```
function click() {
    document.getElementById("<%= ButtonEnter.ClientID %>").click();
}
```

**Code behind**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "Click", "click()", true);
```

Related issues:

[Programmatically fire a button's click event](https://forums.asp.net/t/1340333.aspx?Programmatically%20fire%20a%20button%20s%20click%20event)

[How to programmatically fire the input(button) onclick event](https://forums.asp.net/t/1679231.aspx?How%20to%20programmatically%20fire%20the%20input%20button%20onclick%20event)